# Where are DECLARE_PER_CPU variables stored in kernel

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, macros

I am trying to understand how current macro retrieves struct task_struct of the process.

I am trying to understand for x86 architecture, and after exploring kernel source, struck at the following code:

```
#include <linux/compiler.h>
#include <asm/percpu.h>

#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__
struct task_struct;

DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task);

static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
    return percpu_read_stable(current_task);
}

#define current get_current()

#endif /* __ASSEMBLY__ */

#endif /* _ASM_X86_CURRENT_H */
```

1. Where are the variables declared in DECLARE_PER_CPU stored in memory.
2. Are they at fixed location or in CPU Registers.
3. I am still unable to get, how this will give the task_struct pointer

Can anyone explain it. Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 3):

from what i understood from the sources that i will mention below, the answers to your questions are such:

1. the variables are already defined by the *DEFINE_PER_CPU* macro, and the use of *DECLARE_PER_CPU* is there to tell the compiler that an external reference is being made.
   the section in which *current_struct* variable is stored depends whether the *CONFIG_SMP* is defined on 32bit arch's, if its defined it will be at *".data.percpu"* section otherwise, it will be at *".data"* section.
   In 64 bit arch it will always be at *".data.percpu"*.
   the variables which are declared by *DECLARE_PER_CPU* will be stored on the **stack**.
2. let me qoute:

> On boot up, an area is allocated by the size of the *".data.percpu"* section + 
>      *PERCPU_ENOUGH_ROOM* times *NR_CPUS*.
>      The *__per_cpu_offset[]* array holds the difference between
>   the *".data.percpu"* section and the location where the data is actually
>   stored.
>    *__per_cpu_offset[0]* holds the difference for the variables
>   assigned to cpu 0, *__per_cpu_offset[1]* holds the difference for the
>   variables to cpu 1, and so on.

so, it **depandes on the order of the other declarations of *"per cpu"* variables**

3. the macro per_cpu_read_stable is used to read the *"current_task"* per-cpu variable.

   - https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Concepts/linux-cpu-1.html
   - https://lwn.net/Articles/180101
   - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION
   - [Unable to understand how the "current" macro works for x86 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940893/unable-to-understand-how-the-current-macro-works-for-x86-architecture)